# IIS8 site not working locally to server

Tags: iis-8

New to IIS8, but previously created sites on an IIS7.5 server without any problems. I've created a site on IIS8 and although the pages are being served to remote computers, when I click 'Browse Website' in IIS, the server itself cannot see the page. Any suggestions? Could it be permission based?

I feel this may be linked to a problem we're having downloading images.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention the specifics of "the server itself cannot see the page".  However, since you can access the site remotely but not locally, it sounds like it may be anti-loopback checking.  Check out http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jiruss/archive/2008/10/21/loopback-security-check-feature-iis-7.aspx and see if it applies in your case.